# Altium plated mounting hole, Un-Routed net constraint

Tags: altium, mounting-holes

I am trying to resolve a problem I am having with Altium, maybe I am just missing something obvious but i'd like your insight.

I have a 8 layer board, build out of signal layers, and internal planes.
I recently tried to ground my mounting holes so I plated the pads I use as mounting holes. However after assigning the GND net to my mounting holes and running the DRC, I get an Un-Routed Net Constraints for all my mounting holes.

When I use the 3D viewer everything seems as expected, the internal GND layers seem connected to the mounting hole, and power planes are not connected.
Where do these Un-Routed Net Constraints come from while everything looks the way I want it too?

> The Error I am getting
>
> Class Document    Source  Message Time    Date    No. [Un-Routed Net Constraint
>   Violation]    mypcb.pcbdoc    Advanced PCB    Un-Routed Net Constraint:
>   Net GND Between Pad Free-(162mm,-32mm) on Multi-Layer And Pad
>   Free-(162mm,-32mm) on Multi-Layer     13:53:43    17/01/2019  19

[image: Multiple 3d views grounded mounting hole]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it was something stupid. After trying repours and multiple DRC checks **a simple reboot of Altium solved the issue** and removed the Un-Routed Net Constraint..

PS: Altium Version: 18.1.9(build 240)

Comment: I see that the displayed error lists the hole as a free pad.  You could better future-proof the design by including the mounting holes as a part in your schematic.  This allows you to better manage hole size changes, net connectivity, and support hardware (like bolts, nuts, standoffs that could appear in the BOM).  Yes, with Altium, when in doubt: restart.